# Displaying count query result in Fusion Charts in Dreamweaver

Tags: mysql, dreamweaver, fusioncharts

I am trying to display count query result in fusion charts but the default option is only to select table's columns. I don't want to show column data direct from database instead i want to show total occurrences of a value inside a column e.g If column "Age" includes values 1,23,45,23,23,67,87. I want to display the total number of occurrences of 23 i.e 3 on the fusion chart.

Comment: Why don't you use tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a view that already has the column values you need. Or, add a new column to the existing table. Create a procedure to calculate the values you need.

https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171206?hl=en